# sml standard pop function vs user defiend. And return values

Tags: types, return, sml

i have a few questions about pop() standard function and myPop() function that i have defined and related return type.

1.

`fun myPop(L)= if null L then raise EmptyList else (hd L,tl L)`

```
val myPop = fn:'a list ->'a*'a list
if i want to retrive the value and the list i can write:
val c=myPop([1,2,3]);
val val1=#1(c);
val val2=#2(c);
```

So val1=1 and val2=[2,3].

2.When i use standard pop() I get:

```
val L=[1,2,3]
 pop(L);
val it = SOME (1,[2,3]) : (int * int list) option
```

The question is,is myPop() a right function?How can I get the single values of pop() function?

To get the single values of pop() function i tried this:

```
val L=[1,2,3];
val c=pop(L);
val it = SOME (1,[2,3]) : (int * int list) option // is this like a couple?
val c1=#1(c);
```

But I got this error:

````
  operator domain: {1:'Y; 'Z}
  operand:         (int * int list) option
  in expression:
    (fn {1=1,...} => 1) c```
````

Answer (score 0):

Reworking your code to be a little bit more idiomatic:

```ml
exception EmptyList;

fun myPop([]) = raise EmptyList
  | myPop(x::xs) = SOME (x, xs);
```

A list is not a mutable type. Nor is the `option` type value you're getting from your `myPop` function.

If you want to operate on what's left of the list after `myPop` is called, you need to explicitly pass *that* list to a function call. The original list has the same value after `myPop` is called.

Using `myPop` to implement `iter`, for example:

```
fun iter f lst =
  let 
    val SOME (x, xs) = myPop(lst) 
  in
    f(x);
    iter f xs
  end
  handle EmptyList => ();
```

Of course, we'd really just write:

```
fun iter _ [] = ()
  | iter f (x::xs) = ( f(x); iter f xs );
```

Your specific error is coming from the fact that `SOME (..., ...)` is not a tuple and its contents cannot be accessed with `#1`, `#2`, etc.

However, if we pattern match with the `SOME` constructor, we can get that tuple and then use those accessors on it.

E.g.

```
val SOME x = SOME (1, 2);
#1 x;  (* 1 *)
#2 x;  (* 2 *)
```

A note that if `myPop` returns an option type, then you likely want `myPop []` to return `NONE` rather than raise an exception.